# Allowing client to download files from ftp rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ftp

I'm developping a web application in rails 4 and I'm currenty faced with a tiny issue.

I want to make the users of the website to be able to download files from a ftp by clicking on a link. I've decided to go on this:

```
def download

  @item=Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.dl_count += 1
  @item.save
  url = @item.file_url.to_s    
  redirect_to url and return

end
```

And, very basically, this in my view:

```
<%= link_to 'DL', controller: "items", action: "download"%>
```

However, I'm not quite satisfied by this, as it generates a few mistake like the fact that clicking the link create two GET methods, one responding by 403 Forbidden and the next with a 302 found...

Do you have any idea about how I could improve this?

Comment: Are the files uploaded by users (IE are dynamic), or are they static? If they're static, surely you can put them in the `/public` folder to make them accessible to general users?

Comment: They are dynamic. The reason I chose a FTP hosting is because I wanted to deploy my app on Heroku, so couldn't make a filesystem for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you should do:

```
def download
    @item=Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.dl_count += 1
    @item.save
    url = @item.file_url.to_s    
    send_file url, type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline'
end
```

Take a look for more information http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file

Note that send_file can send only from local file system.

If you need get file from remote source (should be secure location) like http://example.com/apps/uploads/tfm.zip and avoid store this file in server memory, you can first save file in #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/ or system /tmp and then send_file

```
data = open(url)
filename = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/my_temp_file"

File.open(filename, 'w') do |f|
    f.write data.read
end

send_file filename, ...options...
```

If Rails can`t read file, you should check file permission

Comment: I get this error when trying what you said:  Cannot read file http://#addressofmytfp/apps/uploads/tfm.zip